# How to tell webpack about extra dependencies?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, dependencies, webpack-dev-server

Say, you've got some variables you want to share between css and js code:

`vars.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    'body-margin': '100px',
};
```

`style.css`:

```css
body {
    margin: var(--body-margin);
}
```

`entry.js`:

```
var vars = require('./vars.js');
require('./style.css');
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(vars['body-margin']));
```

I do that using `postcss-cssnext`/`postcss-custom-properties` plugin:

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {                         
    entry: './entry.js',                   
    output: {                                                                              
        filename: 'bundle.js',             
    },                                                                                     
    module: {                                                                              
        rules: [{                          
            test: /\.css$/,                
            use: [                         
                'style-loader',            
                'css-loader',
                {loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        require('postcss-cssnext')({
                            features: {
                                customProperties: {
                                    variables: require('./vars.js'),
                                },
                            },
                        }),
                    ],
                }},
            ],
        }],
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
};
```

But when I run `webpack-dev-server` and change variable in `vars.js`, javascript code notices the change, but css code doesn't. Is there a way to fix this? Make css reflect the changes without restarting `webpack-dev-server`. P.S. I'm not dead set on using `postcss`/`cssnext`/`postcss-custom-properties` for sharing variables, if anything.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following way to fix it:

```
diff --git a/webpack.config.js b/webpack.config.js
index 0046862..73c75a1 100644                                               
--- a/webpack.config.js                              
+++ b/webpack.config.js                 
@@ -1,5 +1,20 @@                                    
+var path = require('path');                                         
 var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');           

+var varsFile = './vars.js';            
+                                                                                  
+var postcssCssnextFeatures = require('postcss-cssnext/lib/features').default;
+var customPropertiesPlugin;
+postcssCssnextFeatures.customProperties = (options) => {       
+    customPropertiesPlugin = require('postcss-custom-properties')(options);
+    return customPropertiesPlugin;                  
+};                                     
+                                                           
+function getVars() {                                                
+    delete require.cache[require.resolve(varsFile)];              
+    return require(varsFile);
+}
+
 module.exports = {
     entry: './entry.js',
     output: {
@@ -17,7 +32,7 @@ module.exports = {
                         require('postcss-cssnext')({
                             features: {
                                 customProperties: {
-                                    variables: require('./vars.js'),
+                                    variables: getVars(),
                                 },
                             },
                         }),
@@ -26,5 +41,22 @@ module.exports = {
             ],
         }],
     },
-    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
+    plugins: [
+        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
+        {apply: function(compiler) {
+            compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation) {
+                compilation.plugin('succeed-module', function(module) {
+                    if (module.resource
+                    && module.resource.indexOf(path.resolve('node_modules')) == -1
+                    && path.extname(module.resource) == '.css'
+                    && module.fileDependencies.indexOf(varsFile) == -1   // extract-text-webpack-plugin, for instance, makes webpack build modules twice
+                    ) {
+                        module.fileDependencies.push(varsFile);
+                    }
+                });
+            });
+            compiler.plugin('invalid', function(filename) {
+                customPropertiesPlugin.setVariables(getVars());
+            });
+        }},
+    ],
 };
```

The issues I ran into:

1. `postcss-custom-properties` plugin returns an object with [`setVariables` method](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties/blob/6.0.1/index.js#L277), which can be used to update vars. But `postcss`/`cssnext` doesn't provide an [easy way](https://github.com/MoOx/postcss-cssnext/blob/3.0.2/src/index.js#L74) to access that object. So I monkey patch `postcss-cssnext/lib/features.js`, to intercept the object and put into `customPropertiesPlugin` variable.
2. I can't simply require `vars.js`. The contents is cached.

If you know any simpler way, I'd appreciate it if you told me. Or maybe just an idea. Or a way to improve my solution. Ideally, there must be `postcss` plugin that allows to `@import` javascript files, I guess.